# Sample sequence of points from continuous signal simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a Matlab function (created by me) that must be evaluated only at a given rate. I would like to sample the value of a signal, give to this function (discrete values) and then, the calculated output must be hold until the next value is available. Is there a way in simulink to do this? All answers I have found use quantizer + ZOH but in this case I still get "a continuum" (or almost it) of points to be evaluated by thsi function which is really slow. Changing the rate of simulink's solver is also not an option as the result of this function will be given for a continuous time system.

Any help will be highly appreciatted!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming by `Matlab function` you mean a [MATLAB Function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) block, then it sounds as if all you need to do is make the block discrete.  Do that by right-clicking on the block, going down to `Block Properties` and then in the resulting dialog enter your required sample time.

The block will then sample its input and generate an output (which is held between sample times) at each sample time.